# convert data frame to a panel dataset in r

Tags: r, panel, reshape

I have the following loan dataset. For each loan I have the `amount` requested, the date when the loan is issued `issue_date`, last paymnet received date `last_payment_date`, `months_passed` which is the difference in months between `issue_date` and `last_payment_date`, the loan `term` whether is a 36 for all loans and the `status` of the loan.

Loan status is

(a)"Charged off" if paymnet is late more than 120days, i.e 4+ months

(b)"Fully Paid" if has paid all the loan back

(c)"Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off" same as (a)

(d)"Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Fully Paid" same as (b)

(e) "Default" same as (a)

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("John","Ben","Bill", "Eminem"),
                  amount=c("300", "500", "1000", "1200"),
                  issue_date=c("2010-01-01","2011-01-01","2012-01-01", "2015-02-01"),
                  last_pymnt_date=c("2013-02-01","2012-05-01","2014-01-01", "2018-02-01"),
                  months_passed=c(37,16,24,36),
                  term = c("36", "36", "36", "36"),
                  status=c("Fully paid",
                           "Charged off",
                           "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off",
                           "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Fully Paid"),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Im creating the time interval which will be the first column of the panel as follows

```
time_interval <- as.data.frame(rep(seq(from = as.Date("2007-08-01"),
                                       to = as.Date("2018-02-01"),
                                       by = "month"),
                                   4))
colnames(time_interval) <- c("time")
```

I want to convert it to a **PANEL** dataset by fullfilling the following:

1-Each loan will have the dates from Aug 2007 - Feb 2018 but will appear only when it is alive. That is, if the loan issued in Aug 2008 will appear from Aug 2008 till Aug 2011 i.e 36 rows. Before and after this date we know nothing for the loan, so missing values should be assigned to variables(except the month variable which should be the 1st column).

2-add a column `months` which will be 1,2,3,...,35,36

3- Next to it I want to add another dummy variable `paid` since i want to capture whether  the borrower has made the paymnet of the month or not, based on the `status`. If the loan has `status` is "Fully paid" or "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Fully Paid" than `paid` column will be all ones(1) for 36 months, if `status` is "Charged off" or "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off" we will have ones till the last paymnet date and all zeros after that. For Ben we will have 16 ones and 20 zeros.

See the explanation above for the statuses that will help how to structure the variable `paid`(**VERY IMPORTANT**)

Programing this looks complicated for an amateur like me but it should not be difficult for an expert programmer in R.

Please have a look how a balanced panel dataset structure looks like to better understand what im asking for. All loans are matured.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**sample data**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("John","Ben","Bill"),
                 amount=c("300", "500", "1000"),
                 issue_date=c("2010-01-01","2011-01-01","2012-01-01"),
                 last_pymnt_date=c("2011-01-01","2011-07-01","2014-01-01"),
                 months_passed=c(12,6,24),
                 term = c("30", "30", "60"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   # <<-----  !!!!
```

**data table solution**

```
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )
dt <- as.data.table( df ) #or setDT( df ) when working with (very) large datasets, to save memory
#set data as posix
dt[, `:=`( issue_date = as.Date( issue_date), last_pymnt_date = as.Date( last_pymnt_date ) )]

result <- dt[ , list(id = id, 
                     amount = amount, 
                     month = seq( from = issue_date, to = issue_date %m+% months( as.numeric( term ) - 1), by = "month" ),
                     paid = rep( rep( c(1,0), times = .N ), times = as.vector(rbind( months_passed, as.numeric( term ) - months_passed ) ) )
                     ), 
    by = 1:nrow(dt)][, nrow := NULL]

#        id amount      month paid
#   1: John    300 2010-01-01    1
#   2: John    300 2010-02-01    1
#   3: John    300 2010-03-01    1
#   4: John    300 2010-04-01    1
#   5: John    300 2010-05-01    1
# ---                            
# 116: Bill   1000 2016-08-01    0
# 117: Bill   1000 2016-09-01    0
# 118: Bill   1000 2016-10-01    0
# 119: Bill   1000 2016-11-01    0
# 120: Bill   1000 2016-12-01    0
```

Comment: Thank you. Normally the dataset is big and has a lot of other variables. How should i keep the other variables?

Comment: @Erick, you can create an ID, and then perform a left join, or include them in the `list` when creating the new data.table, like is done in the answer with `id = id,` and `amount = amount,`, just add `yourvan = yourvar,` to the list...

Comment: Wimpel can you please have a look at the qs again? i have updated it. its slightly different. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base R` option.

```
reps <- c(rbind(df$months_passed,
                as.numeric(as.character(df$term)) - df$months_passed))

df2 <- data.frame(id = rep(unique(df$id), df$term), 
                  paid = rep(rep(c(1, 0), length(unique(df$id))), times = reps),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

merge(df, df2, sort = FALSE)
#      id amount issue_date last_pymnt_date months_passed term paid
#1   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#2   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#3   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#4   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#5   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#6   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#7   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#8   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#9   John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#10  John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#11  John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#12  John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    1
#13  John    300 2010-01-01      2011-01-01            12   30    0
# ...
```

The idea is to create a vector that repeats `c(1, 0)` times `months_passed` and `term - months_passed` for each `id`. `df2` contains that information which we can merge with `df` on `id`.

---

Another idea using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[df[, .(paid = `length<-`(rep(1, months_passed), term)), by = id], on = "id"
   ][, paid := replace(paid, is.na(paid), 0)][]
```

Here we create column `paid` in the first place as a vector that contains 1's (repeated `months_passed` times) and `NA`'s using `"length<-"`. This vector will have a length of `term` for each `id`.

Similar to the `base R` solution we join the resulting `data.table` with `df` on `id` after we replaced the `NA`'s by zeros to get desired output.

Comment: Thank you. Normally the dataset is big and has a lot of other variables. How should i keep the other variables?

Comment: I think both answers are quite generic. What went wrong when you applied these approaches to your data? In both answers all you do in the end is join the `paid` column to your existing data.

Comment: i realized that there are some values of `months_passed` higher than the value `term` which gives reps negative

Comment: If the length of column `paid` should not exceed `term` then the `data.table` solution should work fine. Consider to give a more realistic example if it doesn't.

Comment: It returns this error. " Error in as.vector(x, "list") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list' "

Comment: Consider my previous comment.

Comment: Markus can you please have a look at the qs again? I have updated it. its slightly different. Thanks